# Scaffolding db at runtime with EntityFrameworkCore 2.1

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core, scaffolding

I'm trying to scaffold a MSSql db with efcore at runtime, but switches have changed between version 1.x and 2.x and now I don't understand if it's still possibile to run the scaffolding using just the project assembly or if the `.csproj` file is mandatory.

`-a` switch is undocumented (running `dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold --help`) but seems still there, but doesn't seem to work as before, since when I try to pass my `.dll` I get this error:

```
Unexpected value 'c:\blah\MySlnFolder\MyProject\bin\BNB\Debug\netcoreapp2.1\MyProject.dll' for option 'assembly'
```

(of course MyProject has all the EFCore nuget packages needed for scaffolding since I can do it manually from shell with no problem)

Comment: Can you show your code to scaffold?

Comment: `dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold [myconnectionstring]  Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -c Db -f --project myproject.csproj -o efTmp`